# ActiveX under Linux

Tags: activex

Are there any solution besides a Virtual Machine to get ActiveX support under Linux? I mean are there any ways to use IE with wine to get ActiveX?? Or a plugin for Firefox that enables ActiveX?

Comment: I'm not positive about IE under WINE, and I don't know of anything else besides IE that does ActiveX. Upvoted for curiosity.

Comment: /me is struggling to imagine why you would want to do this.

Comment: an intranet website only works on ie6-7-8, ie tab2, so if we use linux for desktop pc we need a vm with a windows xp to use it. that's what we want to avoid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[IEs4Linux](http://www.tatanka.com.br/ies4linux/page/Main_Page) can do this under WINE. Bear in mind however that the default security settings do not allow you to run ActiveX controls, this is true even when run under Windows. To enable them, go to `Tools`, then `Internet Options`, then the `Security` tab, and set the security level to a point where ActiveX controls are permitted to be executed.

Comment: I've done this for something other than activeX.  Sometimes you have to tweak desktop/window decoration settings for IE/wine/plugins to get them working properly.  My use case was Cisco SDM from linux.  Seems pretty retarded since it's a Java app...but Cisco fail.  Anyway, this should work.

Comment: :\ it's not really working.. :\

Comment: "Not really working" is very vague.

Comment: Your IEs4Linux is a dead link.

Comment: @RyanGates It's not dead, the site is just broken. I assume that it will be fixed by the author.